# Rails: How to install CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've installed CanCan and added line `gem 'cancan'` to Gemfile. Ran `bundle`.

I created `app/models/ability.rb` with code:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end
```

**ActiveAdmin** and **Devise** are installed and plugged.

I added `if cannot?` to app/admin/codes.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Code do
  if cannot? :manage, Code
    flash[:notice] = "Access denied"
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  index do
    column :id
    column :title
    column :author
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    column :language
    default_actions
  end
end
```

rails cannot start server or open rails console:

```
app/admin/codes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `cannot?'
for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x4ae7fe8> (NoMethodError)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it.
I have appended code that executes into controller context:

```
  controller do
    before_filter :check_admin

    def check_admin
      if cannot? :manage, Code
        flash[:alert] = "Access denied!"
        redirect_to '/admin'
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

The cancan methods are added to all controllers and models and not anything else, so you will need to manually include the cancan methods in your ActiveAdmin class.  Consider following the pattern here:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb

with something like `include CanCan::ControllerAdditions`

Comment: Thank you. I just added same line, but sessions and redirect_to don't work (I think by the same reason). So now I'm searching for another solution.

Comment: I didn't mean that it would work out of the box, I just meant to use it as a starting point.

Comment: Please look at my solution. Is there any better way to do it?